# Android intent-filter to be notified of an attempt to view a CSV file in the Download Manager

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-download-manager, download-manager

What's the required magic incantation to register your app to be notified that a user is trying to view a CSV file they've **previously** downloaded via the **Download manager**. I've had a brief play and the following filter will happily intercept notifications generated by: Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, Sky Drive, Chrome..... and offer itself to open the files, but my App isn't getting anything when a user attempts to view a file via the Download Manager.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.my.testImportApp.LAUNCH" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PASTE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="ftp" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="data" />
            <data android:scheme="info" />
            <data android:scheme="data" />
            <data android:scheme="smb" />
            <data android:scheme="nfs" />
            <data android:scheme="android.resource" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/comma-separated-values"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/csv"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of playing, the following appears to work:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="ftp" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="data" />
            <data android:scheme="info" />
            <data android:scheme="data" />
            <data android:scheme="smb" />
            <data android:scheme="nfs" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/comma-separated-values"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/csv"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="ftp" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="data" />
            <data android:scheme="info" />
            <data android:scheme="data" />
            <data android:scheme="smb" />
            <data android:scheme="nfs" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.csv" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.CSV" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.txt" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.text" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/comma-separated-values"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/csv"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What is the use for **<category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />**?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need really to play, here is a quick roundtrip to find out what you need.

1. Grep logcat for "ActivityManager: START u0"
2. Place your file in Downloads
3. Open Download App
4. Open your file by click on it
5. Check logcat you should find a line like: `{act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2183 typ=text/csv flg=0x3 ...`

This means your scheme is "content" and your mime type is "text/csv". As a hint when you see the dialog "open with" leave it open and do a `./gradlew installDebug` with your new filter settings and it will immediately appear when you hit the filter conditions in your manifest set.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```